# MapleSoft: solutions to the inverse of a function puzzle

Tags: function, maple, calculus, inverse

I have to find the inverse of a function which looks like: 
**T := ->x (x)^0.5/(x^0.5+(1-x)^0.5)^2.** 
As we can see from the polynomial, we have 4 solutions when solving y= f(x). In maple,I soled for the inverse of T(x)
 **V := x-> solve(t=T(x),x,useassumptions=true) assuming 0<=t<=1.**
and I can evaluate V, i.e maple can do V(0)=0 V(1)=1 etc. 
However, as discussed, there are four solutions to the inverse function, the output of V is an expressions sequence, which looks like (solution1, solution2, solution3, solution4).

In later part of the task, I have to find the derivative of V(x)and integrate it. When I apply diff(V(x),x), maple gives me an error, saying V(x) is not valid.As V(x) is an expression sequence. I tried to use the function D(V), but still no luck.

My questions is how would I be able to handle this V(x) as an expression sequence to finish the rest of the task. Is V(x) a piecewise function? If that's the case, how would I be able to convert this expression sequence to a piecewise function.

Regards,

Comment: Maybe this help :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CINLWZQPew

Answer (score 0):

```
restart:
T := proc (x) options operator, arrow; sqrt(x)/(sqrt(x)+sqrt(1-x))^2 end proc:
V := proc (x) options operator, arrow; solve(x = T(y), y) end proc:
sol := [allvalues(V(x))]:# Extract 4 solution, with command op(1, sol)->Only first solution is correct.

plot([x, T(x), op(1, sol)], x = 0 .. 2, legend = [typeset("Curve: ", "x"), 
typeset("Curve: ", "T(x)"), typeset("Curve: ", "V(x)")]);
```

[image]

```
VV := proc (x) options operator, arrow; evalf(op(1, sol)) end proc;
eval(VV(x), x = 1/2); #Inverse function at point x=1/2
eval(diff(VV(x), x), x = 1/2);# Derivative of inverse function  at point x=1/2
int(VV(x), x = 1/10 .. 1/2, numeric);# Integral of inverse function at range (1/10..1/2)
```

---

**Mathematica 11.3 solution:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It's interesting to see that only the first solution is correct. Before seeing your solution, I copied the first solution and defined it as a function. Y := t-> expression I copied. And then plotted Y. plot of Y and plot of V are different. That's why I was very confused. I think Maple automatically plot the first expression for me when I first approached the question. Thank you again!

Comment: Hey, I have another question. I was trying to solve this: solve(VV(x)<=0.5,x); But the programme doesn't spit out any output. This bothers me a lot.

Comment: And there's also one thing interesting here. The original function was defined with domain [0,1], and co-domain [0,1]. Shouldn't the inverse be defined as [0,1] ->[0,1] as well? In the graph above, the green line V(x) should stop by the point (1,1)? @Mariuszlwaniuk

Comment: @J.W. Domain function `sqrt(x)/(sqrt(x)+sqrt(1-x))^2` is [0,1] and inverse function domain is only [0,1].For `x >1`it's not a inverse function. Have you seen a movie on youtube?.